# How to override padding: 0; from sass?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, nuxt.js

I am working on the footer of my website right now and I am trying to make it responsive. Whenever the screen size gets smaller then 992px I made a media query, so the content of the footer gets centered inside the footer. Before it gets resized I have a column that I put padding: 0; on.

My problem is that I need that padding to be gone in order to center my content, but I need it for the normal sized footer. How can I override the padding: 0; so I can center my content?

Code for normal footer:

```
.social-media {
    margin-bottom: 50px;

    > ul {
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;

      > li {
        > a {
        padding-right: 20px;
        float: left;
        color: #ffffff;
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Code for the small footer:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .social-media {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;

        > ul {
      list-style: none;
      text-align:center;

      > li {
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-right: 10px;

                > a {}
            }
      }

  }
}
```

The code for my bootstrap column:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 offset-lg-6 social">
  <div class="social-media">
    <ul class="nav-items">
      <li class="nav-item" :key="index" v-editable="item" v-for="(item, index) in $store.state.settings.footer_nav">
        <LinkType class="nav-link" :link="item.link" :linkText="item.name">{{ item.name }}</LinkType>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope someone can help me with this problem. I've been stuck on this for a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use '!important' to enforce css properties.

```
.social-media
{
margin-bottom: 50px;

> ul
{
  padding: 10px !important;
  list-style: none;

  > li
  {

    > a
    {
    padding-right: 20px;
    float: left;

    color: #ffffff;
     }
   }
    }
 }

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {

               .social-media
                {

                    margin-bottom: 0;

                    height: auto;
                    width: auto;

                    > ul
                    {
                        list-style: none;

                        text-align:center;

                        > li
                        {
                            padding-left: 10px;
                            padding-right: 10px;

                            > a
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    }

 }
```

Comment: By the sounds of it you want padding when the footer is normal size, and you want 0 padding when the footer is <992px width. So your normal footer will have padding: 10px !important; and your smaller footer will have padding: 0px !important;

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i dont want the small footer to be 0 padding. The 0 padding on the big footer is causing the content in the small footer to be 0 padding aswell wich leads to me not being able to center my content. so i basically want to remove the 0 padding from the small footer.

Comment: @StefandeBoer You can't 'remove' the attribute, it has a value of padding whether it be 0 or something higher. In the media query, you need to set your desired padding value if you don't want it to be 0.

Comment: I guess i have to find another way then. Thank you for your help! i appreciate it!

Comment: @StefandeBoer I would recommend just using inspect element to see what the padding is set to (when it's working the way you wan't) and then set that value yourself in the media query